# File handling POST data not being passed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to do Ajax POST in my WordPress site which is used in checking if checkboxes are checked and getting their values to get updated on the database on click. Using the usual PHP form submit is the easiest but the fields that I'm trying to get is outside the form.

After button click, I created an alert if the data that I need is being picked up (and they are) so I can continue with the Ajax POST. However, the POST data is not showing when I inserted an alert on the second file.

Here's my code (**content-orders.php**):

```
<div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                                <form class="form-inline" method="post">
                                            <select id="bulk_action_stat" name="bulk_action_stat">
                                                <option value="BA">Bulk Actions</option>
                                                <option value="MTT">Move To Trash</option>
                                                <option value="MP">Mark Processing</option>
                                                <option value="MOH">Mark On-Hold</option>
                                                <option value="MC">Mark Complete</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="check-all">Filter</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                                <form class="form-inline" method="get">
                                    <?php $statuses = wc_get_order_statuses(); ?>
                                        <select name="orderstatus" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                                            <option value="any">-- Select Status --</option>
                                            <?php foreach( $statuses as $skey => $status ) : ?>
                                                <option <?php echo ( ( isset( $_GET['orderstatus'] ) && $_GET['orderstatus'] == $skey ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' )?> value="<?php echo $skey;?>"><?php echo $status;?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </select>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                            $status_query = 'any';
                            if(isset( $_GET['orderstatus'] )) {
                                $status_query = $_GET['orderstatus'];
                            }

                            $filters = array(
                                'post_status' => $status_query,
                                'post_type' => 'shop_order',
                                'posts_per_page' => 200,
                                'paged' => 1,
                                'orderby' =>'modified',
                                'order' => 'DESC'
                            );

                            $loop = new WP_Query( $filters );
                        ?>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table responstable table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
                                            <th>Order</th>
                                            <th>Purchased</th>
                                            <th>SKU</th>
                                            <th>Ship To</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Total</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                        if( !($loop->have_posts())) {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="8" class="text-center">No data.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                        } else {
                                            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                                            $loop->the_post();
                                            $order = new WC_Order($loop->post->ID);
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input id="select-item" name="bulk_actions_check" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>"></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $order->billing_first_name." ".$order->billing_last_name; ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <?php
                                                foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
                                                    echo $lineItem['qty']." ".$lineItem['name']."<br />";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><?php
                                            foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $SKUItem) {
                                                    $sku_handler = new WC_Product($SKUItem['product_id']);
                                                    echo $sku_handler->sku."<br />";
                                            }
                                            ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $order->get_shipping_address(); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php explode(" ",$order->order_date); echo $order->order_date[0];?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$".$order->get_total(); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $order->status; ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <form class="form-inline" method="get">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="status_id" value="<?php echo $order->id; ?>" />
                                                    <?php if ($order->status != 'cancelled' && $order->status != 'completed') { ?>
                                                    <?php if ($order->status != 'processing') { ?>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="processing-<?php echo $order->id; ?>" type="submit" name="update_status" value="processing"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                                    <?php }?>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="complete-<?php echo $order->id; ?>" type="submit" name="update_status" value="completed"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                                    <?php }?>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="view-<?php echo $order->id; ?>" type="submit" name="update_status" value="view"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?> 
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#checkAll").click(function () {
             jQuery('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        jQuery('#check-all').click(function(){
            var bulk_action_status = jQuery('#bulk_action_stat').val();
        var checkValues = jQuery('input[name=bulk_actions_check]:checked').map(function()
        {
            return jQuery(this).val();
        }).get();
        alert(checkValues);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { ids: checkValues },
            success:function(data){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

On **test.php**  is just

> print_r($_POST);

These 2 files are in my child theme.

[image]

Comment: You should learn how to use ajax in wordpress https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. anyway if you are doing ajax call not in the wordpress way you probably get 404 error. check your Network in chrome dev and see if its return you 404 error when you call your ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there another way to just make it work? I'm running out of time and I'm not yet familiar with what you suggested.

Comment: You can add to your test.php file at the very top `<?php header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); ?>`

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested @Shibi but I get this error:
`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/dutyfree/wp-content/themes/new-giga-store-child/test.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Ate Marren\htdocs\dutyfree\wp-content\themes\new-giga-store-child\header.php on line 9`

Comment: this error is that you add a require with wrong path.. what that I gave you have no effect on this..

Comment: It's okay now. I dropped the Ajax idea and just focused on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bellend.

The form should just have an ID and add the form ID to all the fields outside the form.

```
<form id="bulk_action_filter" class="form-inline" method="post">
        <select id="bulk_action_stat" name="bulk_action_stat">
        <option value="">Bulk Actions</option>
        <option value="trash">Move To Trash</option>
        <option value="processing">Mark Processing</option>
        <option value="on-hold">Mark On-Hold</option>
        <option value="completed">Mark Complete</option>
        </select>
        <input form="bulk_action_filter" type="submit" name="filter_bulk_actions" id="check-all" value="Apply"/>
</form>
<input form="bulk_action_filter" id="select-item" name="bulk_actions_check[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
```